# Are "find songs demonstrating this technique" questions on-topic?

Tags: discussion

I'm wondering whether I'm allowed to ask for recommended learning material for certain techniques on a specific instrument. Yes, it's subjective, that's why I'm asking.

Is this allowed? The sort of thing I'm imagining is as follows:

> **What pieces can I use to practise classical double stopping on viola?**

This question specifies the instrument, music style, and technique that the OP is looking for. Would this be allowed or is it not within the scope of this site?